# How do I do "or" in Django template code?

Tags: python, django

```
{% if is_loggedin OR is_anonymous %}
test message
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Just thought I would add this http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1350/ which is now apparently in the development version according to the docs @nick referenced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{% if is_loggedin or is_anonymous %}
test message
{% endif %}
```

Like that.

Comment: That doesn't work in the most recent release version (1.1). It's planed for 1.2 release, and indeed is present in the current development version. But for now you can use the custom "smart if" tag: http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1350/

Comment: It should work in the current one: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/builtins/#if. I'm using it. Smart if adds comparisons (>, >=, <, <=, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

> if tags may use and, or or not to test a number of variables or to negate a given variable:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#if

The way you're doing it is fine. :-)

Comment: Thanks. How do I do {% if page = 5 %} ?

Comment: `{% ifequal page 5 %}`. In the dev brunch (leading to version 1.2) `{% if page == 5 %}` will also work.